# How do I find DDE connections and update to OLE connections in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have an access database application, with many connections used to multiple external .accdb files. I have a number of things potentially slowing things down, and I'm trying to solidify the entirety.

The main thing I don't know at this time is how to find what code I'm using that is leveraging DDE instead of OLE, and how to update it to OLE instead (I assume that's the most modern implementation? Or is there something else I should use instead?).

I was cued onto my use of DDE as I got an error stating it was waiting on the DDE connection, which was opened successfully but still waiting on data.

Ideally, I'm looking for something that will convert well to SQL backend databases once I get around to setting those up, but for now I'm using the .accdb backends.

Thanks all!

Comment: Perhaps the [FMS Total Analyzer](http://fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/BestPractices.html)?

Comment: That might help, but it's not cheap.  I'll keep it in mind, though. Thanks!

Comment: True. But an evaluation version is for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Gustav's comment would help anyone else who happens upon my question.

For the purposes of this conversation, however, my tack has changed and I'm migrating to SQL backends now.

Comment: Sorry, what's "my tack"?

Comment: @Pang to "change tack" is a term originally used in sailing, where it means to change your direction. My use of the phrase was a little clumsy though. :)